# Get access to headers in ValidatorConstraint

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm trying to write a custom validation decorator that would prohibit a user from creating an entry with the same title within a single category/subcategory. In order to do that, I'm going to use the class-validator library and write a decorator like this:

```
@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'isUniqueEntryTitle', async: true })
@Injectable()
export class IsUniqueEntryTitle implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
    constructor(
        private readonly userService: UserService,
    ) {}

    public async validate(val: any, args: ValidationArguments): Promise<boolean> {
        return true;
    }

    public defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments): string {
        return `Entry with such title already exists in this folder`;
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that, I will have to make a pretty complex DB query to check whether an entry with such a title is already in the DB or not. One of the parameters, that I need to know is obviously a user id, the user id can be retrieved from the user jwt token but how do I access it inside this class? That's the problem I'm having right now.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to set your validator as Request scoped injectable ([link on documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes)).

This approach allows you inject Request instance to validator and access to user through it.

Briefly it will look like

```js
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';

@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'isUniqueEntryTitle', async: true })
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class IsUniqueEntryTitle implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
    constructor(
        private readonly userService: UserService,
        @Inject(REQUEST) private request: Request
    ) {}

    public async validate(val: any, args: ValidationArguments): Promise<boolean> {
        return true;
    }

    public defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments): string {
        return `Entry with such title already exists in this folder`;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm sounds interesting, lemme try it.

Comment: It does seem like a good plan but I've just tried it and when I try to access the headers by `this.request.headers` I'm getting an error saying: `Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined` which means that `this.request` is undefined. Why could that happen?

Comment: maybe DI container doesn't  know which request it should inject. Try add `import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';` at the top of class. (I've updated answer)

Comment: Or maybe I missed some implementation detail, please try do according this (https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes) instruction

Comment: I did everything according to the docs, you can check it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62522438/unable-to-inject-request-into-a-class-in-nestjs

Yet no success. Any ideas?

Comment: Indeed I've imported all I had to otherwise it would complain with an error. I have no errors but the body is empty.

Comment: that code looks workable, maybe try raise a topic here https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues and create small application for reproducing issue.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what exactly you need. but to make it easy for you, you use this module [nestjs-dbvalidator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@youba/nestjs-dbvalidator)  to check if the colmun is unique or exist

Comment: I'm using the lib called `class-validator` and I'm extremely reluctant to add others just because some technology is not doing something 100% neat. Thank you for the suggestion but I think I will look for some workaround. What I need is simple, I need to get access to headers inside this class. I have not yet figured out how to do that.

Comment: you can do that by creating an interceptor to add the id_user to your request and add an attribute in your DTO, then you can access to this id by `console.log(args.object.id_user); ` , I'm afraid that I didn't explain it well to you, don't hesitate to let me know if you want me to make an example for you.

Comment: I do perfectly understand what you mean. That was actually one of my very first ideas on how to solve this issue but I thought perhaps there could be a better one but now it seems clear that this is the only opportunity that this sh1tty framework allows. The solution above does not work and hell knows why.