# Unable to inject Request into a class in nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator

The class I want to inject the request into looks as follows:

```
@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'isUniqueEntryTitle', async: true })
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class IsUniqueEntryTitle implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
    constructor(
        private readonly userService: UserService,
        @Inject(REQUEST) private request: Request,
    ) {}

    public async validate(val: any, args: ValidationArguments): Promise<boolean> {
        console.log('Request', this.request);
        return true;
    }

    public defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments): string {
        return `Entry with such title already exists in this folder`;
    }
}
```

The corresponding method on the controller looks like this:

```
    @Post()
    public async createEntry(
                             @Body() createEntryBodyDto: CreateEntryBodyDto,
                             @Headers('authorization') authHeader: string): Promise<void> {}
}
```

And finally the `CreateEntryBodyDto` class:

```
export class CreateEntryBodyDto {
    @ApiProperty()
    @IsNumberString()
    @IsOptional()
    id?: number;

    @ApiProperty()
    @IsString()
    @Validate(IsUniqueEntryTitle)
    title: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    @IsString()
    body: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    @IsDateString()
    @IsOptional()
    startDate?: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    @IsDateString()
    @IsOptional()
    finishDate?: string;
}
```

What I get is `this.request` turns out to be undefined. Why would that happen?

Comment: Have you correctly import Request from Nestjs ? `import { Request } from 'express';
`

Comment: @Marco Yeah, that's for sure.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: I had the same issue with a service and what fixed it was to replace `@Injectable` with `@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })`. Leaving this here to hopefully help someone else.